# Why are Guids getting changed to integers in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

When I run `add-migration`, Entity Framework is changing my Guid `Id` datatype to an int in the database. I have two other classes where the field if kept a Guid. Now the column that gets changed is an identity and not null. I assume it's because of it being an identity column. But I see other developers online and their identity field is not being changed to be an int in the database.

Anyone know why this is?

Thanks in advance!

I tried dropping the tables a couple of times but I keep getting the same behavior. I saw some workarounds online but they seem a bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/table-column-properties-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16

Here's what I think (can't comment, sorry):
Identity field is meant to be incremental, that's why you have to choose an Identity Seed and an Identity Increment when enabling Identity an a column.

As you can see in the above link, there is a Column property called RowGuid. I never used It, but maybe it can suit you.

And in my opinion, the reason you

> see other developers online and their identity field is not being changed to be an int in the DB.

is because identity field can be GENERATED BY DEFAULT, using the incremental value except if you provide one.

Source : https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-identity/

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! Thanks for your response!